# UITableView cells stay selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

For some reason after coming back to my parent `UITableViewController` from child `UIViewController`, the selected cell stays highlighted. I've tried the obvious solution below without any luck:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:animated];
}
```

I narrowed the issue down to the following code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *selectedString = [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].textLabel.text;

    if([selectedString isEqualToString:@"Browser"])
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showBrowser" sender:indexPath];
    }
    else if([selectedString isEqualToString:@"Settings"])
    {
        if([[User user] loggedIn])
        {
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showUserSettings" sender:indexPath];
        }
        else
        {
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showLogin" sender:indexPath];
        }
    }
    else if([selectedString isEqualToString:@"Blank Page"])
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showBrowser" sender:[NSURL URLWithString:@"about:blank"]];
    }
}
```

Removing everything in `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` and putting just a single `performSegueWithIdentifier` method WILL deselect the cell once coming back from the child, however what I have now does not deselect it.

I have also tried placing

```
[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];
```

in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method itself with no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you got a custom cell? Is `self.tableView` definitely not `nil`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `[cell setSelected:NO animated:YES]` in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: This works, however it removes the grey line separating it from the cell beneath it. Also, when selecting the cell a second time, it doesn't highlight at all. Any workaround to this?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but this code is working perfectly for me. The grey separator line remains there (for the default cells). Try removing `[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:animated];` from your `viewWillAppear`.

Answer (score 3):

In your `UITableViewController` implement `viewWillAppear` delegate.

In `viewWillAppear` write this line:

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Hope this helps.. :)

**Edit:**

If you reload a cell that cell will be deselected. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10325621/reload-table-view-data-and-deselect-cell) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462393/why-cant-i-call-reloaddata-and-deselectrowatindexpath-in-viewwillappearanimate) will definitely help you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but unfortunately none of the posts on your edit worked either.

Comment: Awesome. I was using a TableViewCell subclass and the highlighted state would stay up if the user slid their finger away from the cell. This worked perfectly when I stuck it in didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: @mondousage > Glad to know.. :)

Answer (score 1):

implement didSelectRowAtIndexPath and write
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

Comment: make sure you set the delegate of tableview.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 [self.tableView reloadData];
```

In ViewWillApear

Comment: What about setNeedsDisplay?

Comment: Tried that as well with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3.1

In `func tableView(didSelectRowAt indexPath)` insert:

`tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)`